# Haskell - manipulating/extending an ADT that isn’t under your control

Tags: haskell, pandoc

What is the best way to go about manipulating/extending an ADT that isn’t under your control? (ie from a dependency)

[Here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/f1278603a4766f32b8375de84b8581f4bb1e665a/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L212) is the data type that relates to my problem:

I want to maintain the structure of the data, but add additional data (ie adding another type), but the structure itself is not under my control. Do I have to map the data over to my own version of this definition?

For example, for all the paragraphs in the structure, I would like `Para` to become `Para [Inline] [String]` where `[String]` is a list of words contained in the paragraph (as it's own data structure).

I am serving this data up as JSON via an endpoint, I thought one way I could get around this would be to define my own `ToJSON` instance, and perform this translation on `Para` there, however I am unable to override the instance as it is already defined! I am willing to accept a solution that does not actually touch the `Para` type itself, I just need a way to couple more data to `Para` without losing any of the structure of full `Pandoc` document.

Comment: Do you need to add more constructors to the type, or merely new fields to existing constructors?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet, but I certainly want to be able to add additional fields to existing constructors at least

Comment: Haskell data types are closed, so I don't believe you can extend the exact ADT without modifying the source code. You could look into extensible types as a solution.

Answer (score 7):

> however I am unable to override the instance as it is already defined!

You could define newtype that wraps a Pandoc, and then define a custom ToJSON instance for that.  `query` from `Text.Pandoc.Walk` could easily and efficiently extract the strings from the Para.

Another thing you might consider is creating a function that wraps each Para inside a Div with the strings stored in one of its attributes.  It wasn't clear from what you said whether this would work for your purposes, but it would be easy to define a function that did this transformation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes I think defining your own `JSON` serializer is probably the best way to go.  You can define `JSON` serializers without using the typeclass mechanism, because Aeson is well-designed (thanks @bos), just define a function from `Block ->`[`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value).  Unfortunately it seems like you will have to traverse every case manually, at least the cases with nested `Block`s such as `BlockQuote`, `OrderedList`, etc.  For the others you can just forward to `ToJSON`:

```
serialize :: Block -> Value
serialize (BlockQuote bs) = object
   [ "type" .= "blockquote"       -- or whatever the encoding is
   , "blocks" .= map serailize bs
   ]
...  -- implement this for every constructor with recursive Blocks
serialize b = toJSON b
```

It's not great, since you might have to directly rewrite things that have been written.  I don't see a way around it given pandoc's design, though (often ASTs are parameterized over a type of annotations, e.g. [haskell-src-exts](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts), or use some open-fixedpoint design, which would allow something more clever).

A rather crude way would be to serialize using `toJSON`, find just the parts of the `JSON` structure you want to annotate, deserialize just that part and compute the annotation, reserialize, then add your computed annotation.  Very ugly, but you don't have to reimplement any serializers, I think.  If pandoc had a *lot* of recursive constructors, or very complex serialization, I might consider this, but as it stands I would probably just bite the bullet and reimplement the recursive cases.